# USB Mouse / Keyboard issues with Linux

Tags: linux, debian, arch-linux, linux-kernel

First and foremost, this problem only occurs when I compile one of the more recent Linux kernels (3.2.6 or 3.2.7). I do not have these issues when running the stock kernel 3.2.6 or 3.2.7 kernels under Debian or Arch Linux.

Approximately every 30 seconds, I get these connect / disconnect events:

```
Feb 22 23:17:46 local kernel: input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input9
Feb 22 23:17:46 local kernel: generic-usb 0003:046D:C05A.0005: input,hidraw0: USB HID     v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input0
Feb 22 23:18:39 local kernel: usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 6
Feb 22 23:18:40 local kernel: usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd
Feb 22 23:18:40 local kernel: usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c05a
Feb 22 23:18:40 local kernel: usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Feb 22 23:18:40 local kernel: usb 1-1.3: Product: USB Optical Mouse
Feb 22 23:18:40 local kernel: usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Logitech
Feb 22 23:18:40 local kernel: input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input10
Feb 22 23:18:40 local kernel: generic-usb 0003:046D:C05A.0006: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input0
```

Last but not least, the USB keyboard is detected and works on boot up, but if I reconnect it, it is ignored. I have compiled HID support into the kernel.

Any suggestions?

Regards,

sinorev

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by switching out mouse. Mouse functions properly, but it's a cheap optical that does the connection drop each time the LED goes out.